# Bash Script sorting array of files by size

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I want to sort the files in my directory by their size. Currently I have found all the files with a certain extension (ie)*.txt) and then added all the values from that list into my unsorted array. I try to sort all the elements in my array by size, but the "-S" on the last line gives me an error.

```
list=$(find . -name "*."$1)
unsortedA=()
for x in $list
do
    unsortedA+=($x)
done

sortedA=( $(for arr in "${unsortedA[@]}" 
do
        echo $arr
done | sort -S) ) #This Line Here*
```

EDIT: All of these lines can be replaced with:

```
list=$(ls -S *.$1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, sorting file listings by size is done with:

```
ls -lS *.$1
```

In any case, `sort -S` is meaningless. `-S` is an option for `ls`; it means something else to `sort`. (And that something else is completely irrelevant here.)

If you want just the list of filenames, sorted by filesize, use

```
ls -S *.$1
```

and pipe it into whatever you want to use for formatting.

Comment: The reason i'm not using ls is because I want to print in a custom format from the array. Is there anyway I can sort by size in an Array?

Comment: @CarlinLiu: basically, no. Please make your use case clearer (by editing your question.)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I just set the ls into a variable and used it in a for loop!

Comment: @carlinLiu: piping it into `while read -r filename; do ... done` is the usual way to handle iterating over filenames. Otherwise, whitespace in the filenames will confuse things. You'll find lots of examples if you look around a bit.